# Vuex - Mutating state with row data of bootstrap table when clicking a row

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuex

I would like to set my state with data from a clicked row in a bootstrap table.

Right now I have my table setup as follow :

```
 <b-table striped
             hover
             responsive
             :filter="filter"
             :items="products"
             :fields="fields"
             v-b-modal.EditProductModal
             @row-clicked="setRow"></b-table>
  </b-row>
```

My state :

```
 state: { // data
products: [],
addeditproduct: {
  name: '',
  description: '',
  externalid: '',
  active: '',
  id: ''
}
},
```

My action

```
setRow: function ({commit}) {
      commit('setRowToState')
    }
```

My Mutation

```
setRowToState (state) {
      state.addeditproduct.name = ''
      state.addeditproduct.description = ''
      state.addeditproduct.externalid = ''
      state.addeditproduct.active = ''
      state.addeditproduct.id = ''
    },
```

Right now it wipes the state but I would like to instead get the data from the row and populate the state with that data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could get better help if we can see the code working and what is not working, you could use https://codesandbox.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Bootstrap Vue here, the component props look similar.

The `b-table` component here, with the `row-clicked` event returns three arguments.

1. the row data
2. index of the row
3. the native event object

You need to rewrite your action and mutation to use that row data returned with the event and update the state. Code follows.

Action:

```
setRow: function ({commit}, rowData) {
      commit('setRowToState', rowData)
    }
```

Mutation:

```
setRowToState (state, rowData) {
      state.addeditproduct.name = rowData.name
      state.addeditproduct.description = rowData.description
      state.addeditproduct.externalid = rowData.externalid
      state.addeditproduct.active = rowData.active
      state.addeditproduct.id = rowData.id
    },
```

Comment: Oh man! Yes I am using bootstrap view. I knew there was something i had to do with rowData from looking at the documentation in bootstrap. Thanks for the help! I've been struggling with this for a while.

Comment: Is there a way to do this same thing but with a bootstrap card component? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53824698/bootstrap-vue-passing-card-data-as-a-payload/53826105#53826105